# Solaris Package Update failing due to incorrect pkg path

Tags: solaris

I am trying to update a Solaris 11.4 box from SRU36 to SRU37 but I am receiving errors due to conflicting attributes.

The package path for SRU36 seems to be missing "/so" from the path but I am unsure as to where this information is pulled from in order to try to alter it, if possible.

```
    The requested change to the system attempts to install multiple actions
    for link 'usr/lib/libcares.so.2' with conflicting attributes:
    1 package delivers 'link path=usr/lib/libcares.so.2 target=libcares.so.2.4.2':
    **pkg:/laris**/library/libcares@1.17.1,11.4-11.4.36.0.1.101.0:20210716T013410Z
    1 package delivers 'link path=usr/lib/libcares.so.2 target=libcares.so.2.4.3':
    **pkg://solaris**/library/libcares@1.17.2,11.4-11.4.37.0.1.101.1:20210825T145948Z
```

I have tried to upgrade directly to SRU38 and SRU39 we same result plus a few other packages throwing the same error.

Any help or advice with this would be greatly appreciated.
Many Thanks in advance

Comment: Also, checking the package info for libcares shows

          FMRI: pkg://solaris/library/libcares@1.17.1-11.4.36.0.1.101.0:20210716T013410Z

so the issue doesn't appear to be with the specific package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What needs to be done:

o ensure that a UTF-8 is used throughout

o remove the cache in the zones (- remove the pkg cache in the zones (cd /var/pkg/cache; rm -rf *))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).